# take specific items from a string and set in other look

Tags: javascript, string, search

i have a javascript that look some pages and it return in a array, all the link i want, for example:

in the array "linkstoopen" ->

```
game.php?page=fleet&galaxy=7&system=3&planet=4&planettype=1&target_mission=16
```

and have others

```
game.php?page=fleet&galaxy=1&system=10&planet=10&planettype=1&target_mission=16
```

i want to take from the array the

```
galaxy = x
system = x
planet = x
```

i already have a `window.location` to open all the items in the array, but now i want to only take from the array the things i mentioned before, and then set they here

```
set galaxy = x above
system = x above
planet = x above

game.php?page=fleet3&mission=16&galaxy=[HERE]&system=[HERE]&planet=[HERE]&planettype=1&speed=100&metal=0&crystal=0&deuterium=0&usedfleet=LGbkBagcBwVkBGgmBwR3BvVlZQNjZQNjZQNjZQNjZQNjZPV7sD==&holdingtime=1
```

and than open this link with the new values in the `window.location`

someone can help how to get the value of every `system=x, galaxy=x, planet=x?`

i think with that i can do alone the rest :S

thx

edit:

i through to get the array with the links, than set to split in the &, than in this new array use the indexof to catch the lines with the system, galaxy, planet, but i think this is a lot of move, there is another easy way?

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions.

```
var link = "game.php?page=fleet&galaxy=7&system=3&planet=4&planettype=1&target_mission=16";
var galaxy = link.match( /&?galaxy=(\d)/ )[1];
var planet = link.match( /&?planet=(\d)/ )[1];
var system = link.match( /&?system=(\d)/ )[1];
```